# output the debug lines to the end of the page

Tags: plugins

Does anyone know a hook, which doesn't depend on the template. A hook I can rely on in any situations?

there's some debug data collected while loading pages (i'm using 'all' hook to collect filter names) i would like to log to the screen. i need the data displayed, say, before

```
</body>
```

tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `shutdown` hook. It runs very late-- "just before PHP shuts down execution" per [comments in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/load.php#L569).

Proof of concept:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', 
  function() {
    echo 'This runs very late in the page load';
  }
);
```

Comment: Oh, I was just thinking about it, actually. Hope it won't cause an infinite loop. Maybe it would be good to hook var_dump into it.

Comment: It is almost always possible to cause an infinite loop. You just have to put your mind to it. :) But whether or not you do cause an infinite loop depends on the code you use in the callback.

Comment: Yep, at least if i use just var_dump, there's no infinite loop. Works great! Thank you!